# div is misaligned when contents are put inside it

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

hi im pretty new to doing front-end stuff i have this div that contains this mini divs inside it when it only have a p tag input here is how it looks like
[image]

but when i added my code for its contents, the div misaligned
and now it looks like this 
[image]

so fare here is the codes im working with

```
<div id="tabular" style="display:none">
        @foreach($NSAdata as $list)

        <div class="divcont">
            <p>Filename :</p>{{$list->filename}}
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

.divcont
{
    background-color: pink;
    display: inline-block;
    width:  300px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
#tabular
{
    height: 28.125em !important;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

any idea what im doing wrong? or to improve my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align: top;` to your inline blocks should fix it.

```
.divcont {
  ...
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

The reason is the default value of [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is `baseline`, when your content inside the inline blocks has different length/height, that causes the mis-alignment.

Answer (score -1):

Inline-block elements are whitespace dependent, which means spaces in your HTML are spaces on screen.

Try and remove the extra blank line at the start of your @foreach loop.

Also add white-space: nowrap; to the #tabular parent div

Comment: You might be thinking of `pre` tags which are whitespace dependent. Inline block elements are not by default whitespace dependent.